# Codeigniter multi-table queries sum, group_by

Tags: codeigniter, group-by, sum, multiple-tables, multiple-select

this query would like to ask for help if someone could, or would a proposal on how to write it over, thank you

```
public function current_user()
{
    //összes számla
    $result = $this->db->select('u.*, sum(a.advance) as advance, sum(p.price) as price')
                       ->from('advance a, products p, users u')
                       ->where('a.user_id = u.id')
                       ->where('p.user_id = u.id')
                       ->group_by('u.name','desc')
                       ->get();
    if($result->num_rows() > 0){
        return $result->result();        
    } else {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It confuses the query

Comment: I would like to achieve that the users table retrieving, the user name. The amount of the advance payments on account for each user table and the products table to the amount of per-user products.